# Equivalent of R's sapply with a condition In Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to convert an R code to Python and need to find an equivalent of sapply in python.

```
data <- data[, sapply(data, class) != "logical"]
```

So what it does is remove logical columns if any from the dataset.

For the below data:

```
Name    Designation         YrofExp     True DS
V       Data Scientist      15          TRUE
P       Data Scientist      10          TRUE
S       Senior Data Analyst 6           FALSE
H       Senior Data Analyst 8           FALSE
```

---

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ï..Name    : Factor w/ 4 levels "H","P","S","V": 4 2 3 1
 $ Designation: Factor w/ 2 levels "Data Scientist",..: 1 1 2 2
 $ Yr.of.Exp  : int  15 10 6 8
 $ True.DS    : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
> data <- data[, sapply(data, class) != "logical"]
> str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ï..Name    : Factor w/ 4 levels "H","P","S","V": 4 2 3 1
 $ Designation: Factor w/ 2 levels "Data Scientist",..: 1 1 2 2
 $ Yr.of.Exp  : int  15 10 6 8
```

I know that the map function can be used like map(function,data) but not exactly sure how in this case.

So can someone please help me out!

Comment: yes `map()` is roughly equiavlent to `sapply` or `lapply` although a list comprehension/generator expression might be more pythonic, can you provide some sample data and the desired transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove from a DataFrame columns by type you can use function 'select_dtypes' on your dataframe:

```
data.select_dtypes(exclude=['bool'])
```

Comment: this is beautiful.. Thanks a lot!